# Sigma Js Oxford Plugin: hovered label active by default

Tags: javascript, plugins, sigma.js

Currently I'm working on a visualisation with sigma js (oxford gephi )plugin -

since it's easily possible to flexibly adjust the size of the label that appears on overnode (hovering on the node), I was wondering if it's possible to make that the default for all nodes of my visualisation on load ?

thanks to you all!

Comment: Make what the default, a certain node size?

Comment: hey - ! No I would like to make the hover-label for a node always active (for all nodes of the visualisation), not just on an mouseovernode event.